# Logstash Iterate inner objects and insert to database

Tags: database, logstash, logstash-configuration, loops

I am new to logstash and i have requirement as flowing scenario. I have following log format.

```
{"library":"xyz","locations":["location1":"abc","location2":"mno"]}
```

Then I need to add these data to database with following format.

- "location" : "library" (database fields)
- "abc":"xyz"
- "mno":"xyz"

So far i have done extract the json and put record to database. But above scenario i need to add two entries to database. I need to know how to iterate location and each location add record to database .documentation link or simple example would be enough.

This is my conf file

```
input {
 file {
   path=>  "filePath"
   start_position => beginning
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
 }
}
filter {

     grok{
       match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:request}"}
     }
     json{
           source => "request"
           target => "parsedJson"
     }

     mutate {
           add_field =>
             "locations" => "%{[parsedJson][locations]}"
             "library" => "%{[parsedJson][library]}"
           }
           remove_field => ["request", "message", "@version", "host", "parsedJson"]
     }

}
output {
  stdout {
  codec => rubydebug
  }
  mongodb{
          collection => "library"
          database => "db"
          uri => "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
  }

}
```

Comment: When you say database, do you mean output in terms of elasticsearch? can you edit your question and add your output config to it?

Comment: Hi @pandaadb i updated configuration file.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: okay - so I think this might not be possible in the way you want it to be. The output only gets 1 event and it submits that event. If you want them to be separate, you need to either (a) create a filter that separates your fields and yields new events (currently only possible with custom filters) or (b) create your own output plugin (based on mongodb) that does the right thing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve what you want with the [`split` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html), which creates separate events for each split of a field. If you had the two locations in a comma separated array you could use

```
split {
  target => "field"
  terminator => ","
}
```

Which would create a separate event for each comma separated value.